# How to Routing joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a componenet in joomla 2.5.

I have several view, in one of then I have a combobox, when I click on it, I want to call a function for that I have this

```
<form class="product_filter" action="<?php echo JURI::root()?>index.php/com_productos/buscarCategoria" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" class="type" name="type" value="HEALTH_FOOD"/>
    <div class="select_wrapper small first">
        <?php echo JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $nameCombo,'name','onChange="this.form.submit()"','value','text'); ?>
    </div>
```

the name of my component is com_productos so in the producto.php I have this

```
class ProductosController extends JController
{
    function buscarCategoria(){
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $view = $jinput->getCmd('view', 'productos');
        JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('view', $view);
        $model = &$this->getModel($view);
        $view = &$this->getView($view, 'html');
        $view->setModel($model, true);
        $view->categoria();
    }
```

but never execute this function.

Any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass task (and controller as part of it) in the hidden field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="productos.buscarCategoria"/>
```

And your action can be simply index.php.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry Rekun thanks for your answer,I pass the task like you said, and obtain this error jos-Error: Invalid controller: name='productos', format='' Can you explain better, sorry about that I am new in joomla,

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem

```
        <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="field" />
        <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_productos" />
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="buscarCategoria" />
    </form>
```

Comment: But why do you pass `name="controller" value="field"`? Have you renamed you controller class to `ProductosControllerField`? Consider to read this about the controllers: http://docs.joomla.org/JController_and_its_subclass_usage_overview . Hope that helps ;)